# jquery how to check <span>.html() == '▴'

Tags: jquery, html

I have html code as:

```
<span id="icon">&#9652;</span>.
```

jquery code as:

```
var icon = $('#icon').html();
if(icon == '&#9652;')
return true;
else return false.
```

the line of code:

```
icon == '&#9652;'
```

always return false.
why is it and how to fix it?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Stylistic note - you can just put `return icon == '&#9652;'`. In terms of debugging, why not [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log) icon to see what value it has

Comment: `&…;` are HTML entities. They only exist in the HTML source code, but not in the DOM (i.e. they are replaced by their corresponding characters during HTML parsing).

Comment: @jackweirdy I'm just give a easy demo.  I'm not actually only return true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check for the unicode of `&#9652;`, which is `U+25B4`:

```
var icon = $('#icon').html();
if(icon == '\u25B4') 
    alert("true");
else
    alert("false");
```

*on a sidenote:* you can also use the hexadecimal unicode number in `html`, just prepend `x`:

```
&#x25B4;
```

Comment: you are welcome! and please consider to accept my answer, if it's the one you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll make life easier on yourself if you check the `.text()` property instead; that way you don't have to worry about HTML entities. For example:

```
var icon = $('#icon').text();
return icon === '▴';
```

If you're testing the HTML instead, then you have to worry if the character is represented by a regular character, a numeric entity, a numeric hex entity, or a named entity in the HTML, though jQuery may be normalizing that.

Comment: Yes, especially if your script is not saved as Unicode for some reason, the escape code is better.

Comment: this is not working because I can not literally write this '▴' in javascript code. it didn't work. however, icon == '\u25B4' works. :)

Comment: Well, you *can* write any character you want; it may just not be in your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob's answer is the correct one...

But, if there's a **really** good reason for comparing the actual HTML notation (i.e. it is dynamic, comes from a database, etc), you could create a compare element with Jquery:

```
var icon = $('#icon').html();
var compare = $("<span>").append('&#9652;').html();
if(icon == compare)
    alert(true);
else
    alert(false)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mL8c9v0n/